# Change size of scatterplot marker based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
{'ScoreDate': {0: '12/1/2019',
  1: '1/1/2020',
  2: '2/1/2020',
  3: '3/1/2020',
  4: '4/1/2020',
  5: '5/1/2020',
  6: '6/1/2020',
  7: '7/1/2020',
  8: '7/1/2020',
  9: '7/1/2020',
  10: '7/1/2020',
  11: '7/1/2020',
  12: '7/1/2020',
  13: '8/1/2020',
  14: '8/1/2020',
  15: '8/1/2020',
  16: '8/1/2020',
  17: '8/1/2020',
  18: '9/1/2020'},
 'CustomerID': {0: 4554,
  1: 4554,
  2: 4554,
  3: 4554,
  4: 4554,
  5: 4554,
  6: 4554,
  7: 4554,
  8: 4554,
  9: 4554,
  10: 4554,
  11: 4554,
  12: 4554,
  13: 4554,
  14: 4554,
  15: 4554,
  16: 4554,
  17: 4554,
  18: 4554},
 'Supplier_Name': {0: 'ABC Company',
  1: 'ABC Company',
  2: 'ABC Company',
  3: 'ABC Company',
  4: 'ABC Company',
  5: 'ABC Company',
  6: 'ABC Company',
  7: 'ABC Company',
  8: 'ABC Company',
  9: 'ABC Company',
  10: 'ABC Company',
  11: 'ABC Company',
  12: 'ABC Company',
  13: 'ABC Company',
  14: 'ABC Company',
  15: 'ABC Company',
  16: 'ABC Company',
  17: 'ABC Company',
  18: 'ABC Company'},
 'Score': {0: 90,
  1: 90,
  2: 90,
  3: 75,
  4: 75,
  5: 75,
  6: 90,
  7: 90,
  8: 90,
  9: 90,
  10: 90,
  11: 90,
  12: 90,
  13: 90,
  14: 90,
  15: 90,
  16: 90,
  17: 90,
  18: 90},
 'EDate': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: '4/1/2020',
  5: nan,
  6: '6/1/2020',
  7: '7/1/2020',
  8: '7/1/2020',
  9: '7/1/2020',
  10: '7/1/2020',
  11: '7/1/2020',
  12: '7/1/2020',
  13: '8/1/2020',
  14: '8/1/2020',
  15: '8/1/2020',
  16: '8/1/2020',
  17: '8/1/2020',
  18: nan}}
```

And some code to produce a line plot of the `Score` with markers for each `EDate`:

```
size = 15
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'large',
      'figure.figsize': (20,8),
      'axes.labelsize': size,
      'axes.titlesize': size,
      'xtick.labelsize': size*0.75,
      'ytick.labelsize': size*0.75,
      'axes.titlepad': 25}
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
plt.rcParams.update(params)

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='ScoreDate', y='Score', ci=None, 
             linewidth=2, palette="deep").set(title="Score")
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='EDate', y='Score', color='orange')
```

Which produces:

[image]

I am looking to accomplish:

- Setting the marker size equal to how many EDates (events) occurred for that date

I have successfully grouped the data using:

```
c_df = df.groupby(['ScoreDate', 'Score'])['EDate'].count().reset_index(name='count')

size = 15
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'large',
      'figure.figsize': (20,8),
      'axes.labelsize': size,
      'axes.titlesize': size,
      'xtick.labelsize': size*0.75,
      'ytick.labelsize': size*0.75,
      'axes.titlepad': 25}
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
plt.rcParams.update(params)

sns.lineplot(data=c_df, x='ScoreDate', y='Score', ci=None, 
             linewidth=2, palette="deep").set(title="Score")
sns.scatterplot(data=c_df, x='ScoreDate', y='count', color='orange')
```

Which produces:
[image]

Which is clearly not what I am looking for. How can I accomplish my three objectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `size` parameter:

```py
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='ScoreDate', y='Score', ci=None, 
             linewidth=2, palette="deep").set(title="Score")

sns.scatterplot(data=c_df, x='ScoreDate', y='Score', size='count', color='orange')
```

Output:

[image]

---

Note: You can also specify the `sizes` (*e.g.* `sizes=[0,30,60,90]`) parameter to manually set the desired sizes for each count group. So, for example:

[image]

See that marker sizes is different (the zeros, for example, not show at all). Alternatively, you can just filter them out from `c_df` with `c_df.query('count>0')` for plotting.

Comment: Your bottom comment -- can you elaborate on what you mean? By group, do you mean `row` in the `count_df`?

Comment: Not the rows. By group I mean each unique count. See the updated answer (I think it's easier to understand by looking at the graphic).